# LaTeX question for \overrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, parallel

I'm new to LaTeX and I have a question about the LaTeX code (which I have to do for my essay), for the inner product of vectors on an exponential*,how can I fix the problem that the two vektors k and x have their vectors taht are not parallel . *The vector of k is much higher that the vector in x* ( I use the command \overrightarrow for the vector, and I have also use the \displaystyle for a sum that exist in the same equation).

How can I fix that?

Thanks cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered, but I believe that there's a solution applicable to a wider variety of situations.

What you call "vector height" can be split up into several different "heights" or "parts of total height" or whatever:

[image]

Now, in your case you want the "height" of both vectors to be equal. However, taking only these "vectors" into account, the solution does not anticipate for characters that also make use of the font "depth" (see picture above).

In `TeX` there's a command that issues a character that stretches across `\totalheight`, but has zero width. In regular text, it is called `\strut`, but in mathmode, it is called `\mathstrut`. Using this command in your `\myvec` will standardize vertical math spacing completely henceforth, and as such, I believe a solution more widely applicable to be:

```
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1\mathstrut}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in your preamble

```
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1\vphantom{k}}}
```

And use it in your document

```
$\myvec{k} \myvec{x}$
```